# Rails, execute sql returns an array of hash

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have following:

```
recs = conn.execute sql
```

output:

```
[{"mk1"=>"test007", 0=>"test007"}, {"mk1"=>"test009", 0=>"test009"}, {"mk1"=>"test0010", 0=>"test0010"}, {"mk1"=>"test00112", 0=>"test00112"}, {"mk1"=>"test345", 0=>"test345"}, {"mk1"=>"testprüfer", 0=>"testprüfer"}, {"mk1"=>"test3455", 0=>"test3455"}, {"mk1"=>"aaaa", 0=>"aaaa"}, {"mk1"=>"pat1", 0=>"pat1"}, {"mk1"=>"pat222", 0=>"pat222"}, {"mk1"=>"poook_patient", 0=>"poook_patient"}, {"mk1"=>"sylviaparient", 0=>"sylviaparient"}, {"mk1"=>"patient_of_sylvia", 0=>"patient_of_sylvia"}, {"mk1"=>"test0005", 0=>"test0005"}, {"mk1"=>"test0006", 0=>"test0006"}]
```

Is there a fast way to get only the values of "mk1"'s by using maybe not "execute" but something else?
I would like to be faster then this one if it is possible:

```
mk1s = []
recs.each{|l| mks1s.push(l["mk1"]) }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you'll always retrieve hashes from the database, if you want something better than your code, use `.map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select_values` method does this.

```
connection.select_values 'select mk1 from ...'
```

would return an array of those values. If your select statement results in multiple columns, it would ignore columns other than the first one.